# var X=Y transferrs string only before white space. Y = regex.exec(string);

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm validating input text to be a-z or A-Z or `\s` ie white space.

```
$scope.change= function(){
var regex = /(?:[a-zA-Z|\s]+)/;
var match = regex.exec($scope.userInputName);
```

The above code works and the `match` captures only alphabets or white space.
However when i put the following statement

```
        $scope.userInputName = match;
```

The `$scope.userInputNam` variable only equates to string before any white space. Thus if `match` held `abc d` `$scope.userInputName` would only equate `abc`

I'm using Angular to call the  name

Comment: How do you know that that's what `$scope.userInputName` contains? The return value of `.exec()` is an array, not a string.

Comment: well, i put `alert($scope.userInputName)` with the statement and without it. in first case it says `abc d` in second case `abc`. But your point of array, and not string, is excellent. so `match.toString()` should do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` will return an array, not a string (or `null` if the string doesn't match).

If you want the matched contents, those are in the first entry in the array:

```
if (match) {
    $scope.userInputName = match[0];
}
```

More in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Answer (score 1):

**I'm validating input text to be a-z or A-Z or \s ie white space.**

In that case your regex is wrong:

```
var regex = /!(?:[a-zA-Z|\s]+)/;
```

It should be:

```
var regex = /(?:[a-zA-Z\s]+)/;
```

`Pipe` is treated a literal pipe character inside character class and there is unwanted `!` in front of regex.

Comment: sorry that was a typo!